# Connecting SQLite3 to Ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite, ios5

I am doing a login and password app, were i want to connect this to SQLite DB, i copied the SQLite framework , imported it and added the db file to support folder but it is not working, please check by code below, and help me out

```
-(IBAction)homePage: (id)sender
{
        post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"loginname=%@ & password=%@",loginName.text,password.text];   
        NSString *hostStr = @"login.db";
       //hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
        NSArray *doumentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentDir=[doumentsPath objectAtIndex:0];
        path =[documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:hostStr];

        if([path isEqualToString:post]){

        homePage *hvc = [[homePage alloc]initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
            hvc.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self presentModalViewController:hvc animated: YES];
}
```

Please let me know hoe to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I think, problem is here...

```
 if([path isEqualToString:post])  // 'post' is your username & password
```

Its should be like this

```
 if([path isEqualToString: hostStr])
```

Try it..

Answer (score 0):

```
         sqlite3 *yourDB;                      // .h declarations
         NSString   *databasePath;
         const char *dbpath;


         call this method at start of viewDidLoad


        - (void) initDatabase
      { 
         BOOL success; 
             NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
             NSError *error; 
             NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                   NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
             NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
             NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory 
                                stringByAppendingPathComponent:@“yourDB.sqlite"]; 
             success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];

         dbpath = [writableDBPath UTF8String];

             // NSLog(@"path : %@", writableDBPath); 
              if (success) return;

             // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the 
             // appropriate location. 
              NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourDB.sqlite"];

         success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:defaultDBPath];
          //if(success) return;

             success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath 
                         error:&error]; 
             if (!success)  
            { 
             NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.”,
                     [error localizedDescription]); 
            } 

        dbpath = [writableDBPath UTF8String];

             NSLog(@"path : %@", writableDBPath);
       }
```